# Add a field to just ONE page

Tags: custom-field, templates

I discovered the 'More Fields' plugin which allows an editor to control which fields appear on which types of items in WordPress. Problem is, I would like to control which pages appear on just ONE page.

Example of this:
- About page has WYSIWYG editor & Image
- Contact page has multiple text fields

From the looks of it, you have to create new page types, but each of them show up in a separate section in the sidebar. I would like everything to appear under my pages tab.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/installation/) plugin.  It supports adding specific custom fields based on various conditions, which range from broad to fine-grained. You can, for example, limit the display of a particular set of custom fields to a particular page id.